# VS 2017 RC - cannot install. A Javascript error occurred in the main process

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Error during installation of Visual Studio Community 2017.
All details on screensoot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ7Ke.jpg

Comment: Hi, which workloads are you trying to install? Can you please run aka.ms/vscollect and post your setup logs somewhere?

Comment: This is a bug in the current version of Visual Studio setup and will be fixed in a later release. Thanks for reporting it! (Disclosure: I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft)